# Prove that $e_k(x)=e^{2 \pi i k x}$ consisting of the functions which are zero on $(0,1)\backslash I$ with $|I|<1$, are not basis for $L^2(I)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let us consider the orthonormal basis $\left\{e_k\right\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ for $L^2(0,1)$ i.e., the functions $e_k(x)=e^{2 \pi i k x}$ and restrict these functions on an open subinterval $I \subset (0,1)$ with $|I|<1$. We can identify $L^2(I)$ with the subspace of $L^2(0,1)$ consisting of the functions which are zero on $(0,1)\backslash I$. Hereby a function $f \in L^2(I)$ is identified with a function in $L^2(0,1)$, which has the expansion
$$f=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle e_k \text { in } L^2(0,1) . \quad (*)$$
Moreover
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\qquad \begin{aligned}
\left.\left\|f-\sum_{|k| \leq n}\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle e_k\right\|\right|_{L^2(I)} &=\left(\int_I\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=-n}^n\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle e^{2 \pi i k x}\right|^2 d x\right)^{1 / 2} \\
& \leq\left(\int_0^1\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=-n}^n\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle e^{2 \pi i k x}\right|^2 d x\right)^{1 / 2} \\
& \rightarrow 0 \text { as } n \rightarrow \infty,
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
$$
and then we also have
$$
f=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle e_k \text { in } L^2(I) . \quad (1)
$$
Define now the function
$$
\widetilde{f}(x)= \begin{cases}f(x) & \text { if } x \in I, \\ 1 & \text { if } x \notin I\end{cases}
$$
Then $\tilde{f} \in L^2(0,1)$ and we have the representation
$$
\widetilde{f}=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left\langle\widetilde{f}, e_k\right\rangle e_k \text { in } L^2(0,1) . \quad (**)
$$
By restricting to $I$, the expansion (**) is also valid in $L^2(I)$; since $f=\tilde{f}$ on $I$, this shows that
$$
f=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left\langle\tilde{f}, e_k\right\rangle e_k \text { in } L^2(I) . \quad (2)
$$
Thus, (1) and (2) are both expansions of $f$ in $L^2(I)$. How can I prove that they are nonidentical? The book from which I taken this example, argues that since $f \neq \tilde{f}$ in $L^2(0,1)$, the expansions (*) and (**) show that
$$
\left\{\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle\right\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \neq\left\{\left\langle\tilde{f}, e_k\right\rangle\right\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \quad (***)
$$
But (1) and (2) are expansions in $L^2(I)$ and $f=\tilde{f}$ on $I$ and I would expect instead that, **on $I$**, $
\left\{\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle\right\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} =\left\{\left\langle\tilde{f}, e_k\right\rangle\right\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}
$. I mean, on $I$, we should have:
$$
\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle=\int_I f\cdot \overline{e_k(x)} dx= \int_I \tilde f\cdot \overline{e_k(x)} dx=\left\langle\tilde{f}, e_k\right\rangle
$$
and thus (***) should be false. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I don't understand what. Somebody help me, please?

Comment: The expansions are valid on $(0,1)$ Hence they are not equal as they represent two different functions. The difference is the function which vanishes on $I$ and is equal $1$ off $I.$ Clearly the Fourier coefficients of the difference cannot be identically $0,$ by the Parseval identity.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, thank you. Can you add some details to your comment please?

Comment: The main point is that in your proof the equality $$\int_I\tilde{f}\cdot \bar{e_k}(x)\,dx =\langle\tilde{f}, e_k\rangle $$ is incorrect. The inner product on RHS  is given by the integral over $(0,1)$ but $\tilde{f}$ is nonzero (equal $1$) on $(0,1)\setminus I.$ So the inner product contains also the additional term  $\int_{(0,1)\setminus I} \bar{e_k}(x)\,dx$

Comment: Oh thank you, it's clear now!

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc : That looks like an answer. Please consider posting it as an answer. The site looks better when questions are officially answered.